# Simple dropdown and ie6 problem

Tags: jquery

I have created a dropdown menu with jquery:
[here](http://www.designer-depot.com/lgn/index.html)
Everything is ok but in ie6. I know ie6 not supported z-index, but is there any solution for ie6?
Thanks in advance

Comment: in ie6, language list pushes search box to bottom. I want to list goes over search box

Comment: "...is there any solution for ie6?". Well yes there is... IE7, IE8, Firefox, Opera, Safari...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hotfile.com uses CSS to achive this effect so that it also works in IE6.
Have a look at the section 2.2 in the [CSS file](http://hotfile.com/styles/structure.css).

Comment: I have solved it but position:relative to outer wrapper. I hate ie6
 Thanks alot